# How to test complex purchasing with phpunit?

Tags: postgresql, unit-testing, common-table-expression

I'm new at unit testing and I think I need test a purchase process,
but it complex.

In our project we have a purchasing process by user
that includes two stages

1. User make an order and user is redirected to paygate.
   We save the customer's email with that order.
2. Paygate send to us order info with payment status (success or fail)
   if success
   we run single complex sql query that using postgresql CTE and
   query creates a user if user doesn't exists, upserts some other rows,
   query also returning email address that using in email message that send 
   to user if new user was created.

I try test second stage.

Exapmles for testing contains tests for simple functions like sum(),
I understand that complex process must be decomposed to simple pieces of code and every piece must be inependent from others.

But how I must test an sql transaction if every result of each query in transaction depends on results of previos query?

For example
upsert user
if user was inserted (if new)
then add user to subscribers table
if user registered from partner then add partner notification about this event
and so on

Previos logic written in single sql query.
How should I test that every query changed data right?

Or should I rewrite cte queries to one-by-one in transaction?
If so, how to understand was new user created or not from transaction?

query now looks like

```
WITH "exists_user"  AS (  
    SELECT "email",0 "created_user"  
    FROM "user"   
    WHERE "email"='email'  
),  
"inserted_user" AS (  
     INSERT INTO "user"("email")  
     VALUES('email')  
     WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM "exists_user")  
     RETURNING "email" ,1 "created_user"  
)  
SELECT * FROM "exists_user"  
UNION ALL  
SELECT * FROM "inserted_user"
```

Comment: returning does not require CTE

Comment: please rephrase the question - what do you want to test?

Comment: @VaoTsun, thank you for help,
I tried to rephrase

Comment: ah, now I get your concern - use `DO` block

Answer (score 0):

[to do some logic between statements, use plpgsl inside](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-do.html) `DO` block, eg:

```
DO
$$
declare
 _email text := 'email@email';
 _c int;
 _t text;
begin
  SELECT count(1) into _c
        FROM "user"   
        WHERE "email"=_email;
  IF _c < 1 then
    RAISE EXCEPTION '%', 'aborting: no email found';
  END IF;
         INSERT INTO "user"("email")  
         VALUES('email')  
         WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM "exists_user")  
         RETURNING "email" into _t;
  IF _t = _email THEN
    RAISE INFO '%',concat('created',_t);
  END IF;
END;
$$
;
```

I know the logic here is nonsense - it's just example of porting your code to plpgsql for logic.

Also you cam put several such `DO` statements in one transaction, eg:

```
BEGIN;
DO.....
DO.....
select now();
END;
```

If any would have an exception, transaction will be aborted